# php if meta shortcode empty dont show, if got text echo text

Tags: php, wordpress

I wan't to show nothing if nothing is displayed in my meta box shortcode:

```
<?php echo stripslashes(do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_matchquote', true))); ?>
```

The meta box shortcode is coded like this:

```
'_'.$dirname.'_matchquote' => array(
    'name' => '_'.$dirname.'_matchquote', 
    'title' => __('Match Quote', 'gp_lang'), 
    'desc' => __('', 'gp_lang'), 
    'std' => '',
    "type" => "textarea"
),
```

So how would i echo nothing if nothing is inside that certain box?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what "that certain box" is but I think this is what you are going for:

```
$text = stripslashes(do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_matchquote', true)));
if (!empty($text)) {
  echo $text;
}
```

I don't understand why you are running `stripslashes` on a processed shortcode. If anything, I'd think it should be run on the output of `get_post_meta` before that string is sent to `do_shortcode`.

```
$text = do_shortcode(stripslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_matchquote', true)));
if (!empty($text)) {
  echo $text;
}
```